# Accessing Directories in C

Tags: c, file, directory, opendir, dirent.h

The program is to open a directory and to display the name of the files...
i.e if there is a file..it should say  FILE....else DIRECTORY..
but the program displays all the files as directory..

Could anyone pls check the code for any errors....thnx

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#define DIR_path "root/test"      
main()
 {
   DIR *dir;
   dir=opendir(DIR_PATH);
   printf("THe files inside the directory :: \n");

  struct dirent *dent;
  if(dir!=NULL)
   {

       while((dent=readdir(dir)))
         {
            FILE *ptr;
            printf(dent->d_name);

              if(ptr=fopen(dent->d_name,"r"))
                {
                     print("\tFILE\n");
                     fclose(ptr);
                }
              else
                    printf("\t DIRECTORY\n");
        }
           close(dir);
    }
    else
            printf("ERROR OPENIN DIRECTORY");

}
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542763/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-the-stat-function-to-test-if-a-dirent-is-a-direc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029633/how-to-use-dirent-h-correctly, and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271064/how-do-i-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-using-c. By the way, this is the ugliest dirent usage I've ever seen. See links for the reason why.

Answer (score 11):

One problem is that a directory is also a type of file, and can be normally `fopen()`ed. You want to call `lstat()` on each file to check whether it is a directory. Like this:

```
struct stat st;
lstat(dent->d_name, &st);
if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
   printf("\t DIRECTORY\n");
else
   printf("\t FILE\n");
```

But this error should lead to all entries being displayed as files. Do you have read permissions for the files in this directory? What is the value of `errno` after the `fopen()` call?

Comment: Actually, you'd probably want to check the return code of **lstat()** for errors.  Within a *readdir()* loop it's unlikely, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `root/test` contains a file called `foo`. The call to `dent=readdir(dir)` sets `dent->d_name` to `"foo"`. You already have debugging output that shows this: `printf(dent->d_name)`¹. Then you try to open `foo` with `fopen`, but the file is actually `root/test/foo`. So this fails every time (unless you happen to also have a file called `foo` in the current directory).

There are two ways to open the right file:

- Construct the full name of the file by concatenating the argument to `opendir` with the file name. Something like:

  ```
  /*before */
  size_t dir_length = strlen(DIR_PATH);
  char *filename = malloc(dir_length + NAME_MAX + 2); /*error checking omitted*/
  strcpy(filename, DIR_PATH);
  filename[dir_length] = '/';
  filename[dir_length+1] = 0;
  while ((dent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      strcpy(filename + dir_length + 1, dent->d_name);
      /*now call lstat, fopen, etc. on filename*/
  ```
- Change into the directory you're listing. For example, change the opendir call to

  ```
  chdir(DIR_PATH); /*error checking omitted*/
  dir = opendir(".");
  ```

  You have to remember to save the previous directory with `getcwd` and `chdir` back to it afterwards. This method is not recommended in production software because it is possible to have a current directory that you can't `chdir` back into due to permissions.

[slacker has already explained why `fopen` can't be used to test if a file is a directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536781/accessing-directories-in-c/3536853#3536853)

<sub>¹ which by the way should be `puts(dent->d_name)` or even better `fputs(dent->d_name, stderr)`: your original `printf` call would break if a file name contains `%`, which is not a big problem for debugging output but is a bad habit to get into.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

its a combination of the two answers by slacker and Gilles.  use lstat but don't use it like slacker said.  You need to send lstat the full path not just dent->d_name.  And just so you know lstat requires you include sys/stat.h>
if you look at the man page for lstat there is a test program at the bottom  or just look at mine.

Here is my program that tries to mimick "ls" on linux.  Note: escape sequence colors doesn't work in windows just in case you were worried about portability.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
 char blue[] = { 0x1b, '[', '1', ';', '3', '4', 'm', 0 };
 char normal[]={ 0x1b, '[', '0', ';', '3', '9', 'm', 0 };
 char green[]= { 0x1b, '[', '0', ';', '3', '2', 'm', 0 };
 char red[]=   { 0x1b, '[', '0', ';', '3', '1', 'm', 0 };
 char cyan[]=  { 0x1b, '[', '0', ';', '3', '6', 'm', 0 };
 DIR* myDirectory;
 char *path=NULL;
 size_t size=100;
 int result;
 char* fullpath;
 if (argc >=3){
   std::cout<<"Usage: myls <path>"<<std::endl;
   return -1;
 }
 if (argc >= 2){
   myDirectory=opendir(argv[1]);
   if (errno==ENOENT){
   std::cout<<"error: file does not exist"<<std::endl;
   return -1;
   }
   path=argv[1];
 if (path[strlen(path)-1]!='/')
strcat(path,"/");
 }
 else if(argc==1){
   path=getcwd(path,size);
   strcat(path,"/");
   myDirectory=opendir(path);
 }
 struct stat fileProperties;
 struct dirent* directory;
 do{
    directory=readdir(myDirectory);
    if (directory!=NULL){
    fullpath=new char[strlen(path)+strlen(directory->d_name)+2];
    strcat(fullpath,path);
    strcat(fullpath,directory->d_name);
    result=lstat(fullpath,&fileProperties);
    //std::cout<<result<<fullpath;
    switch (fileProperties.st_mode & S_IFMT){
      case S_IFDIR: std::cout<<blue;
            break;
      case S_IFLNK: std::cout<<cyan; break;
      case S_IFREG: std::cout<<normal;
      default:  std::cout<<normal;
        if (fileProperties.st_mode & S_IXUSR)
            std::cout<<green;
        break;
      }

      std::cout<<directory->d_name<<"\n";
      std::cout<<normal;
     }
  }while(directory!=NULL);
  std::cout<<normal<<'\n';
  closedir(myDirectory);
  delete[] fullpath;
  return 0;
}
```